# How can I get bash-like job control in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, job-control

I want to configure [zsh](http://www.zsh.org) so that its job control behaves more like (I think) bash does by default. In particular:

1. When I start a background job, it is by default owned by the shell and can be controlled via its job control.
2. When I try to quit once, I get a warning.
3. When I quit again, it is automatically disowned (i.e. **not** terminated) and zsh ends.

I've been testing this by executing `sleep 1000 &` to create a background job. Putting `setopt CHECK_JOBS` in my `~/.zshrc` appears to address point (2) above. However, I cannot get (3) to work; zsh always kills the process when the shell quits. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unset the `HUP` option using one of the following

```
setopt NO_HUP
unsetopt HUP
```